# Kendo: Grid/Ajax - Posting Client Templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid in MVC4 that is working fine:

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<SearchUserResultViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginId);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserName);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserStatus);
          columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserGUID).ClientTemplate(
          "<a href='" + Url.Action("EditUser", "Edit") +  "/#= AppUserGUID #'" + ">Modify</a>");
      })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("SearchUser_Read", "Search").Data("parentModel"))
  )
  .Pageable()
```

However, I wish to user to cause a Post, not a Get when the field AppUserGUID is clicked. Is that possible?

Comment: you are rendering anchor tag not submit button.how it can cause post rather that get?

Comment: I am asking how do I convert it to a Post

Comment: what you want to do?inline(async) edit?

Comment: When the user clicks the Modify, I wish the form to post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change column client template as following :

```
<form action="@Url.Action("EditUser", "Edit")">
Html.Kendo().Grid<SearchUserResultViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.UserLoginId);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserName);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserStatus);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.AppUserGUID).ClientTemplate(
                  "<input type="submit" value="Modify"/>");
      })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("SearchUser_Read", "Search").Data("parentModel"))
  )
  .Pageable()

    </form>
```

you must wrap the grid with a from tag as well.